# GStreamer: Capturing/grabbing upon a signal

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

I need to implement a pipeline with a non-standard video source. This source emits a signal when there is a new frame ready, and the whole pipeline must be synchronized according to this this signal.

The standard sources plug-ins, such a appsrc/fdsrc/etc., are based on basesrc, which (as I understand) uses an internal timer to synchronize the pipeline to a constant and predefined frame rate. This means that I can't use these for my purpose.

Besides implementing a custom plug-in, is there a simple way to achieve what I need?

Comment: Synchronize what to what? `appsrc` sounds exactly the way you would want to do it in my opinion. I would check the Gstreamer pipeline flow in more detail - I cannot see what would prevent anything in your use case.

Comment: By default, the grabbing is controlled by a timer (Which is what I mean by "synchronized"). You set the frame rate, and the source element is responsible of grabbing at that rate according to a timer it uses. I need the source element to grab only upon an outside event, which is not synchronized with the source timer

Comment: So however this looks in detail I imagine this: 3rd party triggers signal, you read data from your app/api generate a GstBuffer, set it's timestamps and push it into `appsrc`. Pipelines can operate in push or pull mode - In this case it's push mode.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. But when you push the buffer, you only put it to a queue, it will be taken out and passed on to the next element's chain callback only on a timer event. So I understand.

Comment: No, it gets immediately send downstream until it hits a sink.

Comment: Well, I have followed the code up to a point in which it seems to wait for a timer event, inside basesrc mainloop code. But if you say this from your experience, I guess I might be wrong. How do I configure the appsrc then?

Comment: The defaults should be good. You only need to set the caps accordingly.